# Изменение цвета клетки поля (php)

Tags: php

Есть код, который строит поле 3x3. При определенных условиях в нажатую клетку поля ставится "0" или "1".

```
public function ShowMap( $game ){
            ?><div class="matrix"><?php
                for( $m = 1, $i = 0 ; $i < 9 ; ++$i, $m <<= 1 ){
                    ?><div class="square" ><?
                        if( $game->Steps( 1 ) & $m ){
                            echo $game->M() ? '0' : '1';

                        }else if( $game->Steps( 0 ) & $m ){
                            echo $game->M() ? '1' : '0';
                        }
                    ?></div><?php
                }
            ?></div><br /><?php 
        }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при первом условии клетка также становилась зеленой, а при втором - красной?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
public function ShowMap( $game ){
    ?><div class="matrix"><?php
    for( $m = 1, $i = 0 ; $i < 9 ; ++$i, $m <<= 1 ){
       if( $game->Steps( 1 ) & $m ){
            $numberStatus =  $game->M() ? '0' : '1';
            $colorStatus = 'green';

        }else if( $game->Steps( 0 ) & $m ){
            $numberStatus = $game->M() ? '1' : '0';
            $colorStatus = 'red';
        }?>
        <div class="square" style="background: <?php echo $colorStatus; ?>">
            <?php echo $numberStatus;?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?></div><br /><?php
}
```

Вот так можно.